# command in shell buffer in emacs in gnu screen

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, gnu-screen

The excellent answer to the question [How do I define an Emacs List function to spawn a shell buffer with a particular command executed in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114577/how-do-i-define-an-emacs-lisp-function-to-spawn-a-shell-buffer-with-a-particular) weirdly does not work in a Gnu "screen" session.  In the context of a screen command, instead of the command I tell it to execute,

```
echo 'test1'\n
```

, Emacs is called recursively!  The would-be shell buffer contains the familiar "emacs: Terminal type "dumb" is not powerful enough to run Emacs" message.

How can I make this work?  Here's what I did:

On the command line:

```
~  srn@basil{1}% screen -s run-emacs2
```

Here is the shell script run-emacs2:

```
#!/bin/bash
EMACS=/usr/bin/emacs23-x
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1  ## suppress annoying gtk>2 warning
exec "$EMACS" -nw --load init.el.test -f spawn-shell
```

NOTE: If on the command line I say:

```
~  srn@basil{1}% run-emacs2
```

...everything works fine.  The problem appears to be some interaction with Gnu screen.

Here is init.el.test (almost verbatim from the answer linked above):

```
(defun spawn-shell ()
  "Invoke shell test"
  (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "gzo")))
  (shell (current-buffer))
  (process-send-string nil "echo 'test1'\n"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior.  According to the [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen) manual, the `-s` option is where to look:

> **`-s`** *program*
>
> Set the default shell to be *program*. By default, screen uses the value of the environment variable `$SHELL`, or `/bin/sh` if it is not defined. This option is equivalent to the shell command (see Shell).

The `screen` program sets the `$SHELL` variable to *program* (as part of opening a new window), and it is inherited in the subprocess, which in turn runs whatever `$SHELL` happens to be.  Since you do not want that, the fix would be to modify the `emacs` script to *reset* `$SHELL` back to `/bin/sh` before running a "shell".